# Best OS for a Pentium IV with 256MB RAM Desktop

Tags: desktop-computer

Please advice a suitable OS for an old desktop having Pentium IV processor with 256MB RAM.

Thanks & Regard,
Hari

Comment: More details like the CPU speed, other hardware, intended use can help narrow down the answers.

Comment: [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) was made for running old hardware like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can run Windows XP just fine with a P4. It [requires only 64MB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314865), so even 256MB is sufficient for most uses. Even so, more RAM is better, so you may want to consider adding a little more (512MB would work perfectly well). You can find cheap or even free RAM through local classifieds like Kijiji, eBay Classifieds, Craig’s List, etc.

Some people will also recommend Linux, so depending on what you want to use it for, you could try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your PC is compatible with Windows XP, but it **might** be kind of slow.
So, try XP <strike>or older version of windows, like Windows 98.</strike>

Your computer is also good for [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

Comment: How would it be slow? A P4 can run XP just fine. -1 for suggesting 98.

Comment: @Synetech - You are absolutely right, but he has only 256MB of ram, which is not the best, you know.

Comment: True, 256MB isn’t a lot, but XP [*requires* only 64MB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314865). Even the recommended amount was only 128MB, so 256MB was plenty. Obviously more is better, but unless they are using it for Photoshop or 3D games, it should still be sufficient.

Comment: Sure, but he will run out of memory very easily, even if he only [browse the web normally](http://lifehacker.com/5976082/browser-speed-tests-chrome-24-firefox-18-internet-explorer-10-and-opera-1212).

Comment: Yeah, -1 for suggesting 98. Not running an up-to-date OS is not a wise suggestion at all...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/), [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), or [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) which will run really well on that older P4...Windows XP SP3 will run very slow on a P4 w/256MB RAM.